# Easy way in C to scale 8-bit number from 0-255 to 0-100 using only 8-bit arithmetic?

Tags: math, scaling

I have an 8-bit unsigned number from 0-255. I need to scale it to 0-100 without using anything other than 8-bit integer arithmetic, including casting, copying to other variables, etc. due to a micro controller limitation.

What is an accurate way for me to do this scaling?

Comment: Why no casting? It's just a reinterpretation of that bit pattern and/or sign/zero extension if needed. Any MCU must have other registers and memory, otherwise it's almost impossible to do anything with only 1 register, so no copying to other variables is also pointless. Declaring a register doesn't mean that it will take some memory space, the compiler will optimize them away if possible

Comment: How about x/2-x/8+x/64 ?

Comment: @DanByström That would scale to 163, not 100.

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc The constant of 8-bit integer arithmetic is imposed upon me. It is not constructive to say that this constraint is useless.

Comment: Use a 256-byte look-up table.

Comment: @ana: i wrote -x/8. MINUS x/8. It would have been 163 if I had written +x/8.

Comment: if you use `x/2-x/8+x/64` or any similar expressions, there's no constraint that the compiler must not create a temporary variable, or use some registers for the temporary value. And in fact it's impossible to calculate that with only 1 memory location or register and nothing else

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use 16 bits for this.

[image: 101 divided by 256]

Put the value in the high byte of a 16-bit register and:

```
x >> 2 + x >> 3 + x >> 6 + x >> 8
```

The result will be in the high byte of the register.

Implementation using only 8-bit registers is left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: This gets you a range of 0-97. I suppose the loss of range is due to lack of resolution of the number and is unavoidable.

Comment: Can't duplicate. `>>> d = 255 * 256`
`>>> ((d >> 2) + (d >> 3) + (d >> 6) + (d >> 8)) / 256`
`100`